# How to run SQL in Intellij from file instead of console

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij 14.1.4. I am able to run SQLs by custom defined db data sources in database console.

I have some sql files in my project and would like to execute them directly instead of copying them to the database console. However, I am not able to use the same data sources that I created for the console when setting up connections from the DB Connections drop down.

I wonder how to run SQL statements from sql files with the same data sources as the ones I defined in the db console?

Thanks

Comment: It turns out that I had the "DB Navigator" installed on my Intellij and it messes with the database configuration in the database view. It works after removing the "DB Navigator" plugin.

Answer (score 8):

You can right-click on an sql file in the editor and there is an option "Run myfile.sql"

[image: SQL run example]

Comment: I don't se that option when I do right click on the file

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-sql-scripts.html for more info on how to configure it

Comment: I have seen this link but the suggestion is the same as what you mentioned here: Do one of the following:
Select Run "<file_name>" from the context menu.
Press ^ ⇧ R.

Answer (score 0):

To run SQL statements from sql files You must associate with file type
[see how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQe2i.png)